# Armature: automatic weights not working correctly

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

I've rigged a few models and automatic weights always worked pretty good, compared to what's happening to me now. Vertices assignment is all over the place and I don't know why. This happened only on 2.79 but it might be an accident. I know automatic-weights isn't perfect, but it used to work so much better in the past for me, way more accurately. Just asking whether maybe patch changed something, or did I mess some options?

[image: Bones "catch" too much mesh]

[image: Leg randomly influences hand]

Comment: Can you upload the file? 

I recently had the same weird weighting occur and the answer was that my normals were pointing inwards in one segment which threw off the calculation.

Comment: Look for (and fix) holes in the mesh.  Automatic weights can "spill" out of these holes and contaminate other parts of the mesh from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

Happend to my model as well, exactly as you described.
Weighting couldn't be solved on the model, so I removed entire head and then applied armature with automatic weighting. Weighting was solved as in the bottom image (some weight, though not visible, was all over model). Then I removed eyes, glued head back to the body and weighting was solved normally.
I had bones sticking out of mesh when got this wrong weighting.
[image]

[image]

Comment: what exactly did you do? Can you explain probably in which situation you removed your eyes from what

Comment: Sorry, I described it completely wrong :-\ I'll edit my answer in a couple of minutes.